# Can I run 32 bit Ubuntu cloud image on a 64 bit Ubuntu server (with Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud 64 bit installed)?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, ubuntu-server

I installed `Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud` on a `32 bit` server. If I decide to later get a 64 bit machine and install `Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud` 64 bit can I still run the images I created on the 32 bit machine on the 64 bit machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - the images on the 32 bit system are likely to be 32 bit, and will run on the 64 bit system

Comment: Is there any documentation on this subject? Thank you!